# AWS Lambda NodeJS Post Request

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to build a simple aws lambda function. Essentially the intent of my alexa skill uses this functionality (I left some empty strings but all should be fine):

```
'use strict';

const Alexa = require('alexa-sdk');
var http = require("https");


const APP_ID = undefined; // TODO replace with your app ID (OPTIONAL).

const languageStrings = {
    'en': {
        translation: {
            SKILL_NAME: '',
            STOP_MESSAGE: '',
        },
    },
    'en-US': {
        translation: {
            SKILL_NAME: ''        
            },
    },
    'en-GB': {
        translation: {
            SKILL_NAME: ''        
            },
    },
    'de': {
        translation: {
            SKILL_NAME: '',
            STOP_MESSAGE: '',

        },
    },
};

const handlers = {
    'LaunchRequest': function () {
        this.attributes.speechOutput = this.t('SKILL_NAME', this.t('SKILL_NAME'));
        this.emit(':ask', this.attributes.speechOutput);
    },
    'Test': function () {

      var command = this.event.request.intent.slots.commandType.value;
      var response = "";
      var self = this;
      if(command === "begin"){
        sendCommand("load", 0, function(res){

          self.emit(':tell', "Command executed");
        });
      }

    },
    'AMAZON.HelpIntent': function () {

    },
    'AMAZON.RepeatIntent': function () {

    },
    'AMAZON.StopIntent': function () {
        this.emit('SessionEndedRequest');
    },
    'AMAZON.CancelIntent': function () {
        this.emit('SessionEndedRequest');
    },
    'SessionEndedRequest': function () {
        //this.emit(':tell', this.t('STOP_MESSAGE'));
    },
    'Unhandled': function () {

    },
};

function sendCommand(commandName, scenarioID, callback){
  var options = {
    "method": "POST",
    "hostname": "someURL",
    "port": null,
    "path": "somePath",
    "headers": {
      "content-type": "application/json",
      "accept": "application/json",
      "cache-control": "no-cache"
    }
  };

  var req = http.request(options, function(res){
    var chunks = [];

    res.on("data", function (chunk) {
      chunks.push(chunk);
    });

    res.on("end", function () {
      var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
      return callback(body.toString());
    });

  });
  req.write(JSON.stringify({ commandType: commandName, scenario: scenarioID }));
  req.end();
}

exports.handler = function (event, context, callback) {
    const alexa = Alexa.handler(event, context);
    alexa.APP_ID = APP_ID;
    alexa.resources = languageStrings;
    alexa.registerHandlers(handlers);
    alexa.execute();
};
```

This works just fine as a standalone script but as soon as I try using sendCommand in an AWS function it does not work anymore.
Can someone please help me on that?

Comment: What kind of error are you getting in the cloudwatch logs?

Comment: @JarredOlson https://pastebin.com/rC8vxBts

Comment: @JarredOlson I edited my aws since the beginning of the question, I updated the question above. Thanks

Comment: I solved it. I had to use http instead of the https lib for whatever reason the endpoint I am targeting does not support https. -.-